# How to remove layers in Keras after loaded a keras model (Efficient Net B7)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.keras, keras-layer

I load the model in this way:

```
model = EfficientNetB7(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=input_shape)
```

What i am trying to do is remove the layer in position:

```
model.layers[1] #Rescaling
model.layers[2] #Normalization
```

What i tried is:

```
del_res= Dense(1, activation='relu', name='remove_rescaling')(base_model.layers[1].output)
del_nor= Dense(1, activation='relu', name='remove_normalization')(base_model.layers[2].output)
```

but the point is that both layers are still there.

I even tried:

```
model.layer.pop(1)
model.layer.pop(2)
```

But nothing to do!!

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: If you're using tf 2.4.1, you can use `pop` method but in a later version you can't;; discussed [here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/15542). And here is an [open ticket](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/16081) to address this, (WIP).

Comment: @M.Innat ok man, many thanks. I read online however that pop create a copy of the structure of the network and then print only the model architecture without the layer popped out: is that true? Or the pop effect for real the model?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to remove specific layers from your EfficientNetB7 model. If deleting the layers directly isn't working, you might need to rebuild the model without those layers.

Here's a suggestion:

```
from tensorflow.keras import applications

inputx = Input((512, 512, 3))
base = applications.EfficientNetB2(
            include_top  = False,
            weights      = None,
            input_tensor = inputx
        )
    

truncated_model = Model(inputs = base.layers[3].input, outputs = base.layers[-1].output) #truncates the functional model
```